# Controlling styles of more than one dive's styles using java script dynamically, using class

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, class

I'm new to `JavaScript`. And suffering from problem...

My structure is something like.....

```
<div id=container>
    <div class="contdiv" data-rate="1.00" id= "l1"></div> 
    <div class="contdiv" data-rate="4.00"></div> 
    <div class="contdiv" data-rate="8.00"></div> 
</div>
```

The number of "contdiv" are not fixed those can be added deleted... so I have to get those dynamically..."data-rate" value is variable to each and want to access it also with JavaScript...
I want to select all divs with contdiv class dynamically with javascript... this I can do with java script..

```
var totalel = document.getElementsByClassName("layer");
```

What I want to do is... I want to access top position of each div and add "data-rate"value to each top position...  this function should be called everytime I move my mouse....

```
<script>
function myfunction(event) {

    var box1 = document.getElementById("l1");
    var obx = box1.offsetTop;
    var newxpos = obx + (here i want "data-rate" value) ; 
    var nxpos = newxpos + 'px';
    document.getElementById("l1").style.top = nxpos;

   }
 document.onmousemove = myfunction;
 </script>
```

Right now i have assigned id for div... but I dont want ID... It should store all divs in variables and should add rates to its top styling grammatically... and this should happen every time i move my mouse... or press any key... (key press is optional)

I know this is lots of work...  But any help I will be really thankful to them...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the whole idea (maybe explain the semantics, not just your technical goal?), but if you want to use non-standard attributes you should prefix them with x (e.g. `x-data-rate="1.00"`). You can read the value in JavaScript with `box1.getAttribute("x-data-rate")`.

Comment: Improved some code snippets, "I" should be used instead of "i"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `getElementsByClassName()` returns an array of elements, you can iterate over them with a for-loop. Attribute values can be requested with `getAttribute()`

```
function myfunction(event) {
  var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("contdiv");
  for(var i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
    var obx = boxes[i].offsetTop;
    var newxpos = obx + boxes[i].getAttribute("data-rate") ;
    boxes[i].style.top = newxpos + 'px';
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply!! :) BUt this will only work if its going to run once... its not working when i run it on mouse move event.... And one more thing... that "Data-rate" value is also changing time to time... i have scripted that value... :( thats why i want to run this function always when i move mouse....  Thank u for ur response sir!!! :)